# Can't restart wso2 identity server after successfull installation

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Yesterday i managed to install successfully the wso2 identity server after experiencing problems regarding the memory allocation. After editing the wso2server.sh to allocate less memory, i managed to run the server. Today, it seems that the problem is not resolved. When i run the wso2server.bat, the same message regarding memory allocation is issued. i tried to change again the shell file with no success.

Has anyone any idea regarding this?

Thanks in advance,
Maria

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: For the record, the error was “Error occurred during initialization of VM; Could not reserve enough space for object heap”.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details? What is Identity Server version? what is physical memory in your machine?  Normally WSO2 Identity Server can be start with 512MB max heap size and run smoothly. Is there any special things that you have done with configurations or any other?

Comment: My PC runs Win XP with 2GB of RAM. I use jdk 1.7.0_45  and the latest version of wso2 server 4.5.0. The only change i made was at wso2server.sh where i changed -Xmx1024m to -Xmx512m. JAVA_HOME variable is also set to the correct path of jdk. Also, i tried to to execute the wso2server.sh instead of the .bat file but it issues a message that it does not support the version of java.

Comment: @Maria wso2server.sh is for linux systems

Comment: Yes... You need to change memory setting inside the wso2server.bat file. You can open wso2server.bat file using a text editor and change memory values.  wso2server.sh file is for UNIX system.